# using apply and lambda to iterate through a dataframe collecting values

Tags: python, pandas

My example is made up.  I'd like to figure it out with apply() and lambda, though I've tried iterrows() too with no luck.  I am trying to add a column to df2, that looks up values in df1, based on the 'item' combinations in each df2 row.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

names= ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

df1 = pd.DataFrame( np.arange(25).reshape(5,5), columns = names, index = names)

n=5
data = {'Item 1' : random.sample(names, n),
        'Item 2' : random.sample(names, n)}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

#I can't get this to work. 
df2['New'] = df2.apply(lambda x: df1.loc[df2.loc[x, 'Item 1'], df2.loc[x, 'Item 2']], axis=1)

#Since this works, I assume my error with apply and lambda.  Thanks.
x=2
df1.loc[df2.loc[x, 'Item 1'], df2.loc[x, 'Item 2']]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df2['new'] = df2.apply(lambda x: df1.loc[x['Item 1'],x['Item 2']], axis=1)
```

output:

```
>>> df2
  Item 1 Item 2  new
0      D      A   15
1      B      B    6
2      A      D    3
3      E      C   22
4      C      E   14
```

Is that what you want? If its not, please add a sample output you want to see.

Comment: Yes.  This is good. Thank you very much.  I moved the brackets a few times, but didn't see that.  What gets bracketed can be confusing.  Outside of lambda, I only used df2.loc[x, 'Item 1']

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid using `apply` in general, and specifically having a `loc` call inside a lambda function. This will get very slow with time.

Use `numpy`'s vectorization instead:

```
r = df2['Item 1'].map(dict(zip(df1.index, np.arange(len(df1.index)))))
c = df2['Item 2'].map(dict(zip(df1.columns, np.arange(len(df1.columns)))))

df2['new'] = df1.to_numpy()[r, c]
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  It looks good and helps me stretch my skills.  I tried it but must be using an older version as I get an error, 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'  It's for a class, so I'm stuck with the version.

Comment: @Glenn use `.values` instead of `to_numpy()` then.

Comment: That works.  I get the right answer, identical to the above solution using `apply`  and `loc`  Thank you again for the follow up.   Truthfully, I am currently more comfortable with `apply` and `loc` but I fully understand your point with respect to efficiency.  I need to study the line more to fully adopt this thinking.

Comment: @Glenn Yes, it's the right answer. But mine is vectorize, which is way faster (for larger datasets). That's the key difference :p

Comment: @rafaelc I haven`t seen you around for a while, nice to see this vectorize solution ;)